# How to use Do Until loop in VBA to select first row with the current date

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have an excel sheet with dates at the beginning of each row in the format of 6/27/2013. I would like to be able to select all rows in the sheet that begin with today's current date, so I wrote the following code:

```
CurrentD = Format(Now(), "M/DD/YYYY")
Workbooks("01 StatorLine.xlsx").Sheets("Downtime tracking").Activate

Range("A4").Select
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = CurrentD
```

It selects the first row that has data, and then should keep moving down the rows until the first row that has today's date is reached. The only problem is that the loop never recognizes the date despite the formats being exactly the same. I tried changing CurrentD to a number and then entering that number into the spreadsheet. When I run the macro in this case it will stop on that number, but for some reason when slashes are involved it won't recognize the cell value and continues looping. I have never used VBA before so any help would be appreciated. Seems like the solution should be pretty simple.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the rows after you select them? You're probably better off using an autofilter instead of a loop.

Comment: `Loop Until Format(ActiveCell.Value, "M/DD/YYYY") = CurrentD` forces the formats to be the same.

Comment: I would like to select the last row with data in it and copy that range to another excel workbook which is the master file. I have been using this piece of code to find the last row with data:

Comment: Lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I will look at using autofilters to streamline the code, thank you all for straightening me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Text` rather than `Value` it will compare the formatted values.

```
Loop Until ActiveCell.Text = CurrentD
```

Answer (score 1):

The string "6/27/2013" and the date 6/27/2013 are not the same thing in Excel.  Even though Excel is showing you a string representation of the date, internally it is storing it as a number.  So you can't compare a string and a date, but you could do this:

```
CurrentD = Format(Now(), "M/DD/YYYY")
Workbooks("01 StatorLine.xlsx").Sheets("Downtime tracking").Activate

Range("A4").Select
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until Format(ActiveCell.Value, "M/DD/YYYY") = CurrentD
```

Now you are comparing a string with a string.